# How to get Name and EmailID from a TextBox?

Tags: javascript

I've added the User Name and Email Id in a text box using following function.

```
function (result) {
var rv = [];
$.each(result, function (i, v) {

rv.push(v.Name +" ("  + v.Email + " )" );
});</pre>
```

And it shows in Textbox like:
**ABC(ABC@XYZ)**

Now I want to access this Name and email Id differently.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you want to do it "differently" but don't say how. _What are you trying to do?_

Comment: what do you mean by access it differently?

Comment: mean to say firstly i want to acces name=ABC and then Email=ABC@XYZ

Comment: How do you want to access the name and email address? Back from the textbox itself? Do you have an id or a specific instance of the textbox? Are you trying to store the name and email address? Do you have a name and want to access the email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the name and email from the textbox value:

```
var textbox = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
var value = textbox.value;
var a = value.indexOf('(');
var b = value.indexOf(')');
var name = value.substring(0, a);
var email = value.substring(a + 1, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You create an HTML element with any custom attributes you want to store multiple values.

Ex:

```
<input ID="userInfo" type="text" userName="ABC" userEmail="ABC@XYZ" value="ABC(ABC@XYZ)" />
```

Then you can query these values in jQuery by their attribute names after getting the html by its name, ID, css... etc

example on how to get attribute value for an element:

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_get.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PLdbr/125/)

```
<div >
   Name & Email <input type="text" id="txtNameEmail" value="ABC(ABC@XYZ)" userName="ABC" userEmail="ABC@XYZ"/><br />
   Name<input type="text" id="txtName" /><br />
   Email<input type="text" id="txtEmail" />
</div>

$('#txtName').val($('#txtNameEmail').attr("userName"));
$('#txtEmail').val($('#txtNameEmail').attr("userEmail"));
```

Comment: did you just copy my solution ?

Comment: did you invented HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but maybe this could do what you want?

```
findByName(rv, targetName) {
    rv.find(function(element, index, array) {
        name = element.substring(0, element.indexOf("("))
        return name === targetName
    })
}

findByName(rv, "ABC")
```

The find function isn't actually available yet in most browsers, but you can polyfill it and get the same functionality (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

You can write a very similar function with the email address.